# What is the general area progression throughout the entirety of the story?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There are certain phases of the story that have to happen in succession to progress through the story of DSII, which areas do I have to visit in which order to completely progress through the story?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have created this image that I print out and mark off as I progress through different characters in order to keep track of progress. It is a work in progress.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the Grave of Saints is optional, and that you don't need to defeat King Vendrick to obtain the Kings Ring (he's also optional). You may want to modify your graph to reflect that. You may want to in the locations of all the Soul of a Giants as well.

Comment: @Wipqozn I am revising it now after a couple of playthroughs. Will definitely add Vendrick as optional, and the Giants as well. I also discovered that every single boss going up to the Lost Sinner is technically optional. There is a way to avoid fighting at least one from every playthough. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160977/what-is-the-closest-fragrant-branch-of-yore-to-majula

Comment: From what I understand you can slip the Last Giant, Pursurer, and Ruin Sententials *or* you can skip the flexile sentry. you do need to beat the dragonslayer so you can unlock huntmans copse.

Answer (score 0):

killing of the dragonslayer is not required to gain passage to huntsmans copse, if you kill the miracle vendor near the bonfire above the dragonrider, you can obtain the charm required to rotate the walls in majula. you also avoid paying her 2000 souls each time you wish to do this. however you must pay souls at her grave to access her merchandise. for all this to be possible, however, you must defeat the dragonrider to gain access to the upstairs. unless there is some workaround for that...

Comment: my apologies, i meant this post as a comment, not an answer! if admins must remove my post for this reason, so be it. only trying to help!